# Why is inline-block position:relative ignoring top offset in percentage?

Tags: css, css-position, offset

I'm stuck trying to figure out why if I relatively position the inline-block select element as it is structured below, it ignores the top offset property in percentage (in ems, for ex, no issue). Without the `p` tags, the offset % works. But once the p tags are back in, `top` % doesn't work. Thanks.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
select {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>some text</p>
  <select>
    <option>apples</option>
  </select>
  <p>some text</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `top: 10%` on an `inline-block`

- works on Firefox
- is ignored on Chrome
- on IE, the percentage is resolved when the page loads, but resizing the window doesn't update it.

I don't think there should be any problem with `top` percentages and `display: inline-block`. The percentages should be able to be resolved correctly with respect to the height of the containing block (unlike margins, `top` only sets an offset, it doesn't affect ancestors, so there is no circular definition). The [containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) doesn't depend on whether its block-level or inline-level, so there is no reason why one should work and the other not.

As a workaround, you can wrap the `select` inside a block element, or style it as a block:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
select {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>some text</p>
<select>
  <option>apples</option>
</select>
<p>some text</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting about how Chrome ignores that. Didn't know.